# Kendo ui sorting column with timespan not working

Tags: c#, kendo-ui

I have a column in my grid where I print values in timeSpan type (using formating "kendo.format('{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00} ..." which prints data correctly.). Unfortunately sorting by this column does not work, while sorting by others does work. Does anybody have clue why it does not work?

Comment: What Kendo's version are you using?

Comment: I used the v2012.3.1114 version.

Comment: Could you put the code please?

Comment: My code: columns.Bound(o => o.Duration.Value.Ticks).ClientTemplate("#= data.Duration==null ? '' :kendo.format('{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}', Duration.Hours, Duration.Minutes, Duration.Seconds) #");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by not working?

If it does not allow you to click on the column then you are most probably using a Template column and Template columns are not sortable.

If you bound the column to the TimeSpan variable and you are using server sorting the sorting should be working.
e.g.

```
columns.Bound(c => c.TimeSpanFieldName)
```

If  you bound the column to the TimeSpan variable and you are using ServerOperation option of the dataSource then sorting wont work properly. And you might need to bind the column not to the TimeSpan property but to the Ticks property of the TimeSpan

e.g.

```
columns.Bound(c => c.TimeSpanFieldName.Ticks)
```

Comment: I bind to Ticks now but I have ServerOperation set to false, and when I click on this column grid fades out and tries to do some operation, which freezes and nothing happens... Is it possible to sort timespan client side? My code:
columns.Bound(o => o.Duration.Value.Ticks).ClientTemplate("#= data.Duration==null ? '' :kendo.format('{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}', Duration.Hours, Duration.Minutes, Duration.Seconds) #");